# Trying to alter the post_content through the_post

Tags: posts, filters, hooks

I'm trying to change the post content of a page by hooking into `the_post` action, but the problem is that whatever I modify in there doesn't really get applied correctly.

The problem seems to come from the fact that `query->setup_postdata` creates a `$pages` variable and sets the content into it before calling the `the_post` hook. So whatever changes I do to the `$post` object doesn't reflect in the page.

Further down the road, it seems that the `get_the_content` function which calls the `the_content` filter uses the content from `$pages` instead of the `$post->post_content`. Thus if I change the content of the post, it will not output it correctly because WordPress bases itself off something else to print out the content.

Now if I hook unto `the_content` filter and replace the text using a simple hook mechanism such as:

```
public function wordpress_hooks_the_title($title){
    if(get_the_ID() == 4){ return 'test title'; }
    return $title;
}

public function wordpress_hooks_the_content($content){
    if(get_the_ID() == 4){ return 'test content'; }
    return $content;
}
```

It works fine for the content, but the title overrides many other titles in the page such as in the menu, even if I call `get_the_ID()` which is fine because the current `$post` is ok.

So I'm stuck trying to find the right way and not a half and half way. I'd like to use `the_post` only or `the_content`/`the_title` only but only half of them work fine in each context.

What would be the right approach?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem and it's about to drive me crazy. The thing is, I have this working on our live site (Manipulating $post->post_content directly), but it isn't working on our development site and I just can't figure out why.

Comment: Sorry @Kevin but this was posted almost 6 years ago. I don't do wordpress anymore and i definitely don't remember the end to that story!

Comment: Hey it was worth a shot :)

Answer (score 4):

It seems you're actually looking for the `the_content` [filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content).

```
add_filter('the_content', 'modify_content');
function modify_content($content) {
    global $post;
    if ($post->ID != $desired_id)
        return $content;

    $modified_content = /* modify content here */;
    return $modified_content;
}
```

Comment: Thats what i'm already doing.

Comment: How can I modify the content like is loaded, not the_content (because it is the plain code), I need get the loaded content and do modify.

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin yout should always use `the_content` inside a [loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). Try preceding the filter order putting it after any others.

Comment: @Milor123 then i think you should look for the `$post->post_content` variable in the loop, as this does not get formatting filters applied.